# Is there a way to avoid labels overwriting in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am experimenting with `Tkinter` to build a GUI that interacts with my database. I'm having issues when executing the same task twice. For example if I search for a specific customer it shows me that customer, if I query for a different customer it shows me that new customer but that label is printed over the previous one. Is there a way to overcome this? I've watched videos from `codemy` where he uses `label.destroy()` and it works perfectly but the same solution in my case generates an error `(label not defined)`. I leave a sample of my code here. Thank you

```
root = Tk()


def search_clients():

    search_clients = Tk()
    searched_label = Label(search_clients) #defined the label

    def search_now():

        global searched_label # made it global
        searched_label.destroy()# erased whatever was in there
        selected = drop.get()
        sql=''
        if selected == 'Procurar por:':
            return
        if selected == 'Nome completo':
            sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nome = %s"
        if selected == 'ID Cliente':
            sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = %s"

        searched = search_box.get()
        name = (searched, )
        result = my_cursor.execute(sql, name)
        result = my_cursor.fetchall()
        
        if not result:
            result = "Record not found"
            searched_label = Label (search_clients, text=result)
            searched_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        else:   
            for index, x in enumerate(result):
                num = 0
                index += 2
                id_reference = str(x[0])
                edit_button = Button(search_clients, text='Editar', command = lambda: edit_now(id_reference, index))
                edit_button.grid(row=index, column=num)
                for y in x:
                    searched_label = Label (search_clients, text=y)
                    searched_label.grid(row=index, column=num+1)
                    num+=1
```

Comment: Two suggestions 1. Create your labels only once and update the text on each search rather than creating new ones. 2. Place your labels etc inside a frame, on a new search destroy all the children of that frame.

Comment: Second suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you scotty3785